# Does AUTOTHROTTLE override DOWNLOAD_DELAY?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The Scrapy documentation for [`AUTOTHROTTLE`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) says, "AutoThrottle extension adjusts download delays." The documentation in the Throttling Algorithm section then goes on to state that "[the] download delay can’t become less than `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` or greater than `AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY`," so I'm assuming they can be used in conjunction with one another?

I'm wondering whether or not `AUTOTHROTTLE` overrides `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, if the values compound, and or whether or not the two settings can be used in conjunction with one another? Definitively which is the case?

Answer (score 2):

> The AutoThrottle extension honours the standard Scrapy settings for
>   concurrency and delay. This means that it will respect
>   `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` options
>   and never set a download delay lower than `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.

I found this note in the documentation and may solve your query.

Comment: i found a similar statement which also somewhat "clarifies" the issue. check my updated Q